# Is using a php if statement as a condition for a javascript if statement unorthodox?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a sign-up page where if there are inputs that are invalid, I assign `$_GET` variables to change the borders of the invalid inputs to be red. If the page is loaded with no `$_GET` variables set, I run into undefined index error so this was my workaround and to say the least, it looks messy. Is their a cleaner way to do this?

```
<script>
if(<?php 
  if(isset($_GET['email_Error'])){
    echo 1;
  }else{
    echo 0;
  } 
?> == 1){
$("#email").css('border','2px solid red');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. Just output the JavaScript only if that condition is true. That way you don't have unnecessary JavaScript in your page and it is clearer to read.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['email_Error'])): ?>
<script>
$("#email").css('border','2px solid red');
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```